# I have an if-else rules decision tree file , and want to visualize it, How can i do that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygraphviz

> I have generated a decision tree using the C4.5 algorithm, and the tree is generated and stored in `rules.py` as if-else rules.
>
> Now I wanted to visualize the decision tree in rules.py. I have seen some tutorials of graphviz but I am not able to visualize it.
>
> Below is the `rules.py` file :

```
def findDecision(obj): #obj[0]: Semester, obj[1]: Gender, obj[2]: Friend_time, obj[3]: Faculty_visit, obj[4]: avg_attendance, obj[5]: attentive_class, obj[6]: participation_corricular, obj[7]: study_time, obj[8]: social_time, obj[9]: cgpa, obj[10]: extra_crse, obj[11]: health, obj[12]: sleep, obj[13]: go_out_frnd, obj[14]: lib_time
   if obj[9]>2:
      if obj[14]>2:
         if obj[12]>1:
            if obj[3]>1:
               if obj[7]>1:
                  return 5
               elif obj[7]<=1:
                  return 4.5
               else:
                  return 4.5
            elif obj[3]<=1:
               return 5.666666666666667
            else:
               return 5.666666666666667
         elif obj[12]<=1:
            return 6.5
         else:
            return 6.5
      elif obj[14]<=2:
         if obj[11]>1:
            if obj[8]>1:
               if obj[2]>2:
                  return 6.0
               elif obj[2]<=2:
                  return 7
               else:
                  return 7.0
            elif obj[8]<=1:
               return 6
            else:
               return 6.0
         elif obj[11]<=1:
            return 8.0
         else:
            return 8.0
      else:
         return 6.7272727272727275
   elif obj[9]<=2:
      if obj[7]>1:
         if obj[1]>1:
            return 8
         elif obj[1]<=1:
            return 9
         else:
            return 9.0
      elif obj[7]<=1:
         return 7.0
      else:
         return 7.0
   else:
      return 8.125
```

So can please help me how to visualize this ?

Comment: it seems the output of chefboost framework. Does not the framework support visualization?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pythontutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/) to visualize code.